# After change to new computer I can't access any of my external devices

Tags: permissions, sd-card

Ubuntu 16.04

I bought a new computer and did a clean install.  When I put in any of my SD cards or external thumb drives, every file on the card is locked (shows a padlock).

Not only can I not access these files but I can't even copy files to the SD card.

How can I change access rights on external media?

Answer (score 0):

Well I might know the solution but I need toknow a few things as well. 
The first is are you using the GUI version of the terminal version of ubuntu?
secondly is what version of ubuntu are you using?

now for solutions that might remove or bypass the problem

Solution 1
If the sd card doesn't allow you to ut files on or retrive files the switch on the SD card might be on the lock position, the simple fix is to put it in the ther position
Solution 2
If the switch is in the right position and still can't acces the files, try giving your account name and password from your old pc to the files, I don't know if you have to do this if you try opening a file or in it's settings since every file wants it different (in my experince)
Solution 3
If the second solution didn't work or can't be done try unlocking the files on your old pc, by giving permission to the everybody tag in the settings of the file.

i hope one of these solutions has solved your problem if not i will look further into it

Comment: What is  `the other position`?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen well on the SD cards i have there is a small lever/slide which you can put in the lock or open position. in the lock position the files can't be accesed, moved from the SD or something on the SD. and the open is the opposite of that ofcourse

Comment: I've tried manipulating the lock switch, when locked I can't do anything with the drive, when unlocked it says everything is read only and I don't have permission.

Comment: my "about" says ubuntu 16.04 LTS  os type 64 bit

Comment: "Solution 2
If the switch is in the right position and still can't acces the files, try giving your account name and password from your old pc to the files, I don't know if you have to do this if you try opening a file or in it's settings since every file wants it different (in my experince)"

- not sure how to do that

Comment: "Solution 3
If the second solution didn't work or can't be done try unlocking the files on your old pc, by giving permission to the everybody tag in the settings of the file."  - I tried this and when I save it, the save doesn't take.

Comment: If I change my access from access files to create and delete files, it changes for a split second and then changes back.  For "other's access" the same.  If I change "permissions for enclosed files," for owner and group the permissions are "read and write," and "create and delete files," but for others, "read only," and "access files."  I change the latter to match the former and nothing happens.  I go back in to "change permissions for enclosed files" and it is the way it was before.

Comment: @76767676 did you save the setting changes? and that setting to give it a password and user should be in one of the setting tabs. but i have limited experince with the GUI of Ubuntu, so i am going on what i can remember and perhaps you can make a duplicate file which you give everyone(not the tag) acces to the file then just yourself.

Comment: I saved and when I came back, it is the same as when I found it before.

Comment: @76767676 okay, i did some digging around and i think this might help. it is going to sound very simple but if you still have acces to your old computer try and sending the files to yourself with an e-mail. otherwise i have a last resort option but that is as i say last resort. which is to open the file and open an empty version of the program you are using and copying the text, images, lines of code, ect in to that empty file and this time save it giving everyone acces